# Create multiple AlarmManager for the broadcast receiver?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager, android-broadcast

I am calling a `BroadcastReceiver` through `AlarmManager` And It works fine for me.

**But**

What I need this time

***`I want to create multiple AlarmManager which call the same BroadcastReceiver Class.`***

What is the way to do this process?

Comment: what does different-different time mean...?

Comment: @JoxTraex : I remove that keyword .

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do that by Setting alarms with a **different request code** for the `PendingIntent` used. Make sure every alarm will have a unique request code. Then receive them with a single broadcast receiver.

Another thing to be kept in mind, if device reboots then pending intents no longer exists. So, you have to use another receiver for determining if a device reboots. You have to save your unique request codes, then When the device reboots you have to restore your alarms with the same request codes. Hope it helps.

Edit:

BroadCastReceiver

```
package com.your.package;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;

public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String Noti_title = intent.getExtras().getString("title");
        String Noti_message = intent.getExtras().getString("notes");
        int Noti_code = intent.getExtras().getInt("code");
        Log.d("AlarmReciever", Noti_title + " " + Noti_message);
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(context, NotificationService.class);
        myIntent.putExtra("title", Noti_title);
        myIntent.putExtra("notes", Noti_message);
        myIntent.putExtra("code", Noti_code);
        context.startService(myIntent);
    }
}
```

Service :

```
package com.your.package;

import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.Ringtone;
import android.media.RingtoneManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.IBinder;

public class NotificationService extends Service {

    private NotificationManager mManager;

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings({ "static-access", "deprecation" })
    @Override
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
        super.onStart(intent, startId);

        String Noti_title = intent.getExtras().getString("title");
        String Noti_message = intent.getExtras().getString("notes");
        int Noti_Code = intent.getExtras().getInt("code");

        mManager = (NotificationManager) this.getApplicationContext().getSystemService(this.getApplicationContext().NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        Intent intent1 = new Intent(this.getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);

        Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.ic_launcher , Noti_title , System.currentTimeMillis());
        intent1.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

        PendingIntent pendingNotificationIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this.getApplicationContext(), 0, intent1, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

        notification.setLatestEventInfo(this.getApplicationContext(),Noti_title , Noti_message , pendingNotificationIntent);
        notification.vibrate = new long[] { 100L, 100L, 200L, 500L };
        mManager.notify(Noti_Code , notification);
        try {
            Uri notification_uri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
            Ringtone r = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(getApplicationContext(), notification_uri);
            r.play();
        } catch (Exception e) {}
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onDestroy();
    }

}
```

Usage :

```
public void SetAlarm(Calendar calendar, int reqCode) {
        String dateName = idea.getText().toString();
        String dateNote = note.getText().toString();
        Log.d("SetAlarm Texts", "Date : " + dateName + " Note: " + dateNote);

        Intent myIntent = new Intent(mActivity, AlarmReceiver.class);
        myIntent.putExtra("title", "Her : " + dateName);
        myIntent.putExtra("notes", dateNote);
        myIntent.putExtra("code", reqCode);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(mActivity,
                reqCode, myIntent, 0);
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) mActivity
                .getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),
                pendingIntent);
    }
```

Comment: okay, I'll change the value of request code and after reboot also manage that value ....Now,  I am also sending a string into a broadcast receiver class on every alaramManager call and all the time string value is change . How can I handle that value in it ??

Comment: I am attaching codes I have done before , hope you'll get the idea how to handle your String.

Comment: @ayon posting code doesn't typically always answer a question, its more important to understand the concept and THEN grab the code, not grab the code and ignore the concept... Also full work code samples lead to less of an understanding than small code snippets with a small explanation.

Comment: Yeah, you are right. I agree with you. But As its relevant to this context , so posting code samples seems better and quick solution for me.

Comment: Can you give a bit of idea to after the restart phone how can save the String value for each request code .....

Comment: Well , For my case, I used database. I saved the Alarm Strings, Request Codes in the sqlite database. Then, In the BroadcastReceiver I started a service.The service fetched all alarm info from database and checked if the alarm time has expired or not. If not then simply reset the alarms with same String and Request Code from the cursor by the method described in my answer.

Comment: @Ayon I am not using Broadcast receiver but using a service where i have notification which i want to display on every scheduled alarm. Any idea how would you do it? BTW your email is not listed on your profile. Would you mind sharing? Thanks

Comment: You will need to use NotificationManager and Pending Intent for that. When the time comes for Alarm , just make a Notification and display with Pending Intent. Here's a article that describes the process very precisely. http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidNotifications/article.html

Comment: My email is ayon@dhrubokinfotech.com @Reaz P

Comment: What if the alarm didnt go off will it go off next time the device is rebooted?

Comment: Id suggest using an Intentservice if the the task is relatively simple , just use OnHandleIntent method and do processing by get extras from the broadcast receiver similar to the explanation above.